# the result does`t match what I expect when I used log-normal PDF in matlab

Tags: matlab

I`m learning a paper

the paper presents a figure
[image]

the figure shows CDF of buildings height
and the paper also gives details about this figure

> Building height statistics: The present model uses the statistics of
>   building heights in typical built-up areas as input data. A suitable
>   form was sought by comparing with geographical data for the city of
>   Guildford, United Kingdom. The probability density function that was
>   selected to fit the data was the log-normal distribution with unknown
>   parameters: mean value p and standard deviation t. As can be noted
>   from Fig. 3, it was found to be a good fit to the geographical data
>   values with parameters p = 7.3m, t= 0.26.

it tells the mean value is 7.3 and the standard deviation is 0.26 right?

however, when I try them in matlab by adding codes

```
x=0:0.01:20;
meanValue = 7.3;
standardDeviation = 0.26;
y1 = logncdf(x,meanValue,standardDeviation);
plot(x,y1);
```

what the result showed is different from the figure 3
[image]

I tried to re-read the paper to make sure parameters are correct.
and check the document on matlab about how to use this method.
everything seem all right except the simulation result.

please help me fix it ! thanks

Comment: Mu and Sigma are not  median and variance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: yes, I checked the document of matlab, the parameters in logncdf( ) are mean value and standard deviation

Comment: That's wrong: "mu and sigma are the mean and standard deviation, respectively, **of the associated normal distribution.**"

Comment: sorry. I cannot understand. From [link](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/stats/logncdf.html)  first line of Description.`"mu and sigma are the mean and standard deviation"`. Even I use these two parameters in normal distribution. The result doesn`t match what I expect as well. Could you show me how to fix the code?

Comment: Read the full sentence. I is the mean and variance **of the associated normal distribution.**, not the mean and variance of the log normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the parameters mu and sigma are the mean and standard derivation of the associated normal distribution, not of the log normal distribution. The details, especially the connection between both is [explained in the Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

To calculate mu and sigma from the mean and variance, the formulas are given in the Wikipedia article [or here in the matlab syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognstat.html?refresh=true):

```
m=7.3
t=0.26
v=t.^2;
%A lognormal distribution with mean m and variance v has parameters
mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2));
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));
%finally your code:
x=0:0.01:20;
y1 = logncdf(x,mu,sigma);
plot(x,y1);
```

[image]

Which is much closer to the graph in your question, but the graph in your question seems to be the CDF for a much higher standard derivation. Visually guessing the parameters form your plot, I would say it's roughly `t=5`